# can not printing array's item in another function

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this:

```
function func1()
{
$web( 'news' => 'yes',
      'items' => '');
// I call `$web['item']` and fill it as array:
$web['item'][] = 'item1';
$web['item'][] = 'item2';
$web['item'][] = 'item3';
foreach($web['item'] as $item) echo $item,'-';
//result: item1 - item 2 - item 3 

func2($web)
}
```

Now everything sound good...but when I send $web to another function it just print.

```
function  func2($web)
{
  foreach($web['item'] as $item) echo $item,'-';
  //result: item1 - 
}
```

What is my wrong?

Comment: It makes a little more sense now that you don't have a sentence in the middle of your func1.

Comment: I'm assuming this is example code because this has a syntax error where you create the array $web because you are using parenthesis instead of brackets and a syntax error where you use func2() but otherwise this works fine...

Comment: You should look into how to declare arrays in PHP a little. Everything else is okay in all honesty.

Answer (score 0):

You have issues with and arrays. To declare a new array you have some options. I like the shortest way, personally:

```
$web = [];
```

Put it all together with the corrections.

```
function func1()
{
    $web = [];
    $web['item'][] = 'item1';
    $web['item'][] = 'item2';
    $web['item'][] = 'item3';
    foreach($web['item'] as $item)
    {
        echo $item.'-';
    }

    echo "<br>";
    func2($web);
}

function func2($web)
{
    foreach($web['item'] as $item)
    {
        echo $item.'-';
    }
}
```

I added an `echo "<br>";` so results would appear on separate lines. I didn't include lines that weren't too useful for this example, you may add those back in.

Comment: You can concatenate with a comma too.  I know, confusing, but PHP allows it.  There is no issue present except for the syntax errors in this example code.